# Get index of a dayname based on Week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using the following query, we can get the index of weekday of today or a specific date :

```
Select DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
```

But i need to know the index of a dayname. Like i have `Friday` and i want to get 6, how can i get it?

**More clarification**

I can achieve the result using `IF ... ELSE` like below :

```
Declare @DayName varchar(50)
Declare @DayIndex int

set @DayName='Friday'

if @DayName='Saturday'
    set @DayIndex=7
else if @DayName='Friday'
    set @DayIndex=6

... so on
```

So my question is :

**Question :** Will the day index be same in any `regional settings` of the system if i use the above approach? I am indicating `@@datefirst`, in my system it's value is `7`, what if it's value is `1` in other system?

Comment: In fact `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2018-01-26')` _does_ return `6` (which is a friday)

Comment: @mshsayem - I know, but i have only `Friday` or `Sunday` etc and i want get the index like 6 or 1 etc.

Comment: `CASE` it is, then. See first answer.

Comment: @mshsayem - Didn't get the desired answer yet.

Comment: The answer below should be sufficient. You can convert it to a function by `CREATE FUNCTION DayIndex(@DayName as varchar(50)) RETURNS INT AS BEGIN {function body} END`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer of Pரதீப் first. You can convert that to a user defined function like this (taking account for `@@datefirst`):

```
CREATE FUNCTION DayIndex(@DayName as varchar(50)) 
RETURNS INT AS 
BEGIN 
Declare @DayIndex int;
SELECT @DayIndex = CASE LOWER(@DayName)
                    WHEN 'sunday'   THEN    1+(7-@@datefirst)%7
                    WHEN 'monday'   THEN    1+(8-@@datefirst)%7
                    WHEN 'tuesday'  THEN    1+(9-@@datefirst)%7
                    WHEN 'wednesday'THEN    1+(10-@@datefirst)%7
                    WHEN 'thursday' THEN    1+(11-@@datefirst)%7
                    WHEN 'friday'   THEN    1+(12-@@datefirst)%7
                    WHEN 'saturday' THEN    1+(13-@@datefirst)%7
                   END;
RETURN @DayIndex;
END;
```

And use it like this:

```
SELECT [dbo].[DayIndex] ('Friday');
```

Test 1:

```
set language US_ENGLISH;
select dbo.DayIndex('Sunday') Sunday
,dbo.DayIndex('Monday')    Monday
,dbo.DayIndex('Tuesday')   Tuesday
,dbo.DayIndex('Wednesday') Wednesday
,dbo.DayIndex('Thursday')  Thursday
,dbo.DayIndex('Friday')    Friday
,dbo.DayIndex('Saturday')  Saturday;
----- result -------
 Sunday Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday
 1      2       3       4           5           6       7
```

Test 2:

```
set language ITALIAN;
select dbo.DayIndex('Sunday') Sunday
,dbo.DayIndex('Monday')    Monday
,dbo.DayIndex('Tuesday')   Tuesday
,dbo.DayIndex('Wednesday') Wednesday
,dbo.DayIndex('Thursday')  Thursday
,dbo.DayIndex('Friday')    Friday
,dbo.DayIndex('Saturday')  Saturday;
----- result -----
Sunday  Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday
7       1       2       3           4           5       6
```

Comment: You can then use `@@datefirst` instead of the constants.

Comment: How can i use it ?

Comment: Fixed. Try now.

Comment: Awesome! Can't say thanks as it is prohibited here :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `CASE` statement

```
Declare @DayName varchar(50)
Declare @DayIndex int

set @DayName='Friday'

SELECT @DayIndex = CASE @DayName
                     WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 1
                     WHEN 'Monday' THEN 2
                     WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 3
                     WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 4
                     WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 5
                     WHEN 'Friday' THEN 6
                     ELSE 7
                   END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i was not looking for it, perhaps i didn't explain good what i need. So i have added more clarification, please check.

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir - Updated.. you can convert this to function if needed