# Can we get day number by passing day name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get a day number of the week from day name in sql server without hard coding? 
Some thing like this

```
select DatePart(xx, 'Monday') 
result: 1
```

Comment: since there are only 7 possibility, can you use a simple `CASE WHEN` statement ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get index of a dayname based on Week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380187/get-index-of-a-dayname-based-on-week)

Comment: @Squirrel yes true mate, but I have very large table, so was wondering if there is any built in function to do it.

Comment: what does a `CASE` statement got to do with large table ?

Comment: @Squirrel i have dynamic query where its not possible for me to do the case statement, but I just realized we have a day number column along side. That will solve my problem. Thanks for advise, I would have used the case if I could have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the day number for a date object like this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
```

There isn't enough info in 'Monday' for SQL to infer a date; you're just converting text to a number at that point. But, if you must, at least write a function you can reuse:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DayNameToDayNumber(@DayName VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE @DayName
        WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Monday' THEN 2
        WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 3
        WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 4
        WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 5
        WHEN 'Friday' THEN 6
        WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 7
        ELSE NULL
        END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called DAYOFWEEK designed to return the day number corresponding to the date passed. Its format is:

```
 select {fn DAYOFWEEK(getdate())}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a solution that is independent of `DATEFIRST` and language

```
; WITH 
week_day AS
(
    SELECT  date_part = datepart(weekday, datecol), date_name = datename(weekday, datecol)
    FROM    (
            VALUES 
            (GETDATE()),     (GETDATE() + 1), (GETDATE() + 2), 
            (GETDATE() + 3), (GETDATE() + 4), (GETDATE() + 5), (GETDATE() + 6)
        ) v (datecol)
)
SELECT  *
FROM    week_day
where   date_name   = 'Tuesday'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found below example by googling.

```
declare @m varchar 
set @m=0 
SELECT DATENAME(DW,CAST(@m AS INT))
```

[How do you print the day name given a day number in SQL Server 2005 using SQL commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554714/how-do-you-print-the-day-name-given-a-day-number-in-sql-server-2005-using-sql-co)